# Which sentence is correct, "The shop is open" or "The shop is opened"?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

As for "The shop is open" or "The shop is opened",which sentence is right?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is an interesting question. We often do use the [past participle form of a verb as an adjective](http://funeasyenglish.com/american-english-grammar-past-participle-adjective.htm), but as Zero's comment and kiamlaluno's answer indicate, *opened* is "non-standard" in OP's context.

Having said that, I think [there is evidence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20opened%20bottle,an%20open%20bottle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) that native speakers are trying to "regularise" things...

[image]

A similar trend seems to be happening with [adjectival **roasted**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20roasted%20chicken,the%20roast%20chicken&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [**cleaned**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20cleaned%20clothes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), for example. So my guess is if OP lives long enough, he may eventually be able to refer to *an opened shop* quite naturally.

---

Picking up on my first sentence, it's worth noting that there are two "adjectival" forms derived from the verb *to interest*. Both are common, but they have different meanings...

> I am interested *- something/someone is exciting my interest*
>    I am interesting *- I am [capable of] exciting someone else's interest*
>    *I am interest *- would normally be considered completely unacceptable*

Comment: I see the point you're making, but I think with specific regard to *open* there are two sense of the word at play here. I would easily speak of an *opened bottle* or an *opened package* (items which were sealed and are now opened) but for a shop, which opens in a different sense and closes again daily, I wouldn't use *opened* so easily. So I can't say, of course, that this won't change over time, but I do think there are two different senses of the word here, and that with *shop* such a change seems less likely to me. +1 regardless!

Comment: @WendiKidd: I certainly agree it feels "easier" to use the past participle *opened* with things like bottles (i.e. - things which normally start off *closed, sealed,* and are only likely to be *opened* once to attain the new state). But if the trend is real, and it continues long enough, people might eventually start to see an *open shop* as a linguistic anomaly that needs to be brought into line. Whatever - my motivation in making this point was to reassure learners that it's not completely ridiculous to see our current idiomatic preference as perhaps "slightly illogical/confusing".

Comment: I see a difference in meaning between adjectival *cleaned* and adjectival *clean*, kind of parallel to the difference between "this room needs cleaning" and "this room needs to be cleaned".

Comment: @Martha: Are you sure you're not "post-hoc" rationalising from the fact that two different verb forms can be used in that context? As I understand it, Pennsylvanians at least are quite happy to say *this car needs washed* where most of us say *this car needs **washing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you mean I'm supposed to be sure of things? *Now* you tell me... As far as the Pennsylvania dialect thing, I don't know if it has been established as fact that "this car needs washed" is the same as "this car needs washing" (rather than "this car needs to be washed").

Comment: @Martha: I mean **I** can't see any semantic distinction being made in either of these two cases in the last 3 comments. But I can certainly see a potential difference between *the room needs to be **clean*** and *...needs to be **cleaned***. In the first version it's possible nothing actually needs to be done (apart from maybe *confirming* that the room is in fact already clean, and/or will remain clean for as long as the stricture holds).

Comment: "This room needs cleaning" means that if you run the vacuum over exposed surfaces, you've satisfied the requirement. "This room needs to be cleaned" means that you actually have to clean the room as thoroughly as you can. Of course, if the first sentence was spoken by your mother, then you need to interpret it as if she said the latter sentence, but that's politics, not linguistics.

Comment: @Martha: That's *your* distinction - which as I said, I don't recognise. Those two "nuances" might even apply the other way around, noting that 0.53% of all GB instances of *needs cleaning* are preceded by ***really***, but only 0.21% of *needs to be cleaned* are thus emphasised. That's of nearly 300,000 in total, so could well represent a genuine usage tendency.

Comment: If I were to say ”That shop was opened by a local mafioso”, I wouldn't be allowed to replace ”opened” with ”open”, right?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko In that case, it's the passive form of the verb. You cannot use _open_ in that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

[Open](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/open) is an adjective, and you should say "The shop is open."

> Is the museum open on Sundays?

> I declare this festival open.

Comment: You may add that "opened" can be used for physical objects with "doors": e.g. "the box was opened"...

Comment: As @FumbleFingers answer shows, with physical objects, native speakers tend to use _open_ (the adjective). _The box was opened_ could be using the passive form of _open_ (the verb).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant to say is that while "opened" can be used with physical objects (at least in some situations), it cannot be used with "festival" or "mind". However, "open" can be used with "everything".