# Are they the same in meaning, the open door and the opened door?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between "the open door" and "the opened door"? Are they the same in meaning? Please explain it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/which-sentence-is-correct-the-shop-is-open-or-the-shop-is-opened

Answer (score 5):

*Open* is an adjective.

*Opened* is a past participle used as a modifier.

The difference in meaning is that *open* is in contrast to *not open*. The door  could have been open for ten years or a century. It could always be open.

*Opened* expands to *The "having been opened" door...*

This refers to the action of the door having been opened. The door used to be shut, now it is open. It has been opened. It has not always been open. It could have been opened ten years ago or two  seconds ago, but at some point it was closed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the difference between the open door and opened door is one of time. The open door refers to one that is open and has always been open, the opened door refers to one that has only recently been opened.

Comment: "The open door" has no implication that the door has *always* been open, although it allows that possibility because it has no information about the door's past state at all. "The opened door" must have been closed before it could have been opened, but we don't know how recently or how often.

Answer (score -1):

In practice, they are exactly the same thing. But open door is the common expression. Nobody says opened door.

In terms of English rules and all, see other answers. In terms of natural English, see this answer.