# Leave the door open vs Leave the door opened

Tags: difference

Is there any subtle difference between:

- We need to carry in some stuff so open the door and leave it **open**.
- We need to carry in some stuff so open the door and leave it **opened**.

I mean **"leave it like that (in that state)"**.

Comment: Perhaps not so clearly with **leave**, but there is a subtle difference between "I want the window open" and "I want the window opened".  We'd normally use the latter if the window is not yet open and we're obliquely directing someone to open it.  *I want your bedroom tidied*. That might be paraphrased as "When I check in on you later, I want your bedroom to be tidy. I want you to have tidied it."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yeh, I know this difference. Thanks. But what about **"leave it open(ed)"**?

Comment: **open** refers to the door's state and **opened** refers to the door's having been *placed* in its state, when the verb is transitive. When the verb is intransitive, the past participle refers to the thing's having *entered* its state.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Understanding this, I cannot see a difference of any kind with "leave".

Comment: As I said, "Perhaps not so clearly with **leave**..." , which would mean "allow it to remain" in the state in which it has been placed or which it has entered, *mutatis mutandis*, when used with the pp.  When used with the bare adjective, "allow it to remain in its state".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85418/are-they-the-same-in-meaning-the-open-door-and-the-opened-door As for a shop, see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/which-sentence-is-correct-the-shop-is-open-or-the-shop-is-opened

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments you seem to understand the subtle difference in nuance between the two requests.  "Leave something open" implies keeping it in a particular *state* while "Leave something opened" implies keeping it in the state that exists as the result of some *action*.    There is a slight difference in focus between the window itself, and the window *plus* whoever (or whatever) *opened* it.

However there is little if any difference in *meaning*, since the desired end result -- the open window -- is the same.

Comment: Yes, however, there is a difference when speaking about an open shop. I doubt "opened" will work.

Comment: It's the same for a shop, and just as uncommon.  It might make perfect sense in the right context.